# Typescript React createContext and useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm new to TS and trying to update code that I inherited from a former employee. I know it's TS related and have tried different types not able to resolve it. Any assistance would be great. Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react';

export interface HistoryType {
  history?: number;
  setHistory: (value: number) => void;
}

const HistoryContext = React.createContext<HistoryType | undefined>(undefined);

export const HistoryProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [history, setHistory] = React.useState();
  return (
    <HistoryContext.Provider value={{ history, setHistory}}>
      {children}
    </HistoryContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useHistoryState = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(HistoryContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('useHistoryState error');
  }
  return context;
};
```

Screenshot of the error:

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [history, setHistory] = React.useState()
```

Since no type is specified here, typescript has to try to infer it. It sees that `undefined` is implicitly being passed to use state, so it assumes the state is (and always will be) `undefined`. So that means that `setHistory` expects to be passed `undefined`.

You will need to specify the type yourself to say that it can either be a number, or undefined:

```
const [history, setHistory] = React.useState<number | undefined>();
```

Or if it's always supposed to be a number, you can do that too, but you'll need to provide an initial value which is a number:

```
const [history, setHistory] = React.useState<number>(42);
```

---

P.S: This is unrelated to your question, but i notice this code is employing a [common mistake](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats): You're creating a brand new object on every render and passing it as the context value.

```
value={{ history, setHistory }}>
```

Since there's a new value on every render, it will force anything that's consuming the context to rerender even if history and setHistory did not change. To fix this you should memoize the value so it only gets recomputed when it actually changes:

```
  const value = React.useMemo(() => {
    return { history, setHistory };
  }, [history]);

  return (
    <HistoryContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </HistoryContext.Provider>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas for the solution. I also modified the code and included useMemo.